# optimize if statement R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a three vectors VC, A and B. Depending on the length of the two vectors A and B, I give different values to the matrices/variables D.2, D.3 and sigma.sq.
I would like to optimize this code, which seems a bit repetitive, but could not figure out a way. I suppose ifelse() is not feasible in this case, it is?
Code below:

```
VC <- c( 242.048101,   4.712942, -24.758050,   4.752800,  45.329368)
A <- c(1,2)
B <- c(1) 
len_rTrms1 <- length(A)
len_rTrms2 <- length(B)

if ((len_rTrms1==2) & (len_rTrms2==1)){
  D.2 <- matrix(c(VC[1],VC[3],VC[3],VC[2]),2,2)
  D.3 <- VC[4]
  sigma.sq <- VC[5]
}

if ((len_rTrms1==1) & (len_rTrms2==2)) {
  D.2 <- VC[1]
  D.3 <- matrix(c(VC[2],VC[4],VC[4],VC[3]),2,2)
  sigma.sq <- VC[5]
}

if ((len_rTrms1==1) & (len_rTrms2==3)) {
  # if random slope at level 3
  D.2 <- VC[1]
  D.3 <- matrix(c(VC[2],VC[5],VC[6],VC[5], VC[3], VC[7], VC[6], VC[7],VC[4]),3,3)
  sigma.sq <- VC[8]
}

if ((len_rTrms1==2) & (len_rTrms2==2)) {
  # if random slope at level 3
  D.2 <- matrix(c(VC[1],VC[3],VC[3],VC[2]),2,2)
  D.3 <- matrix(c(VC[4],VC[6],VC[6],VC[5]),2,2)
  sigma.sq <- VC[7]
}


if ((len_rTrms1==1) & (len_rTrms2==1)) {

  D.2 <- VC[1]
  D.3 <- VC[2]
  sigma.sq <- VC[3]
}

VarCorRes <- list(D.2 = D.2, D.3=D.3, sigma.sq=sigma.sq)
```

Comment: It is also a matter of taste. But I would go with `if (a == 1) {if (b == 1) ... else if (b==2) ... } else if (a == 2) {if (b==1) ... else if ...}` and so on.

Comment: it just seemed more clear to me in the way I wrote it...given that I have to share my code with co-authors. But do you think your way would be faster?

Comment: In this case speed is not a concern as checking those statements is pretty fast. If you counted the checked statements my proposed way would be faster, because it does not have to check so many statements. To increase your speed a bit and keep your readibility you could still use `else if` and use `&&` instead of `&`. The latter is for vector comparisons and not needed here.